# Why is no output displayed in Udacity, although the code works in a Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, output

When trying to solve tasks in Udacity by changing only inputs, the code doesn't want to display any outputs. I tried to edit the code and click test run but it doesn't display anything; it only displays "Your code displayed no output". I copied the code to a Jupiter notebook and there it works.

Code

```
import pandas as pd

# TODO: Set weight1, weight2, and bias
weight1 = 1
weight2 = 1
bias = 0.5


# DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW
# Inputs and outputs
test_inputs = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
correct_outputs = [False, False, False, True]
outputs = []

# Generate and check output
for test_input, correct_output in zip(test_inputs, correct_outputs):
    linear_combination = weight1 * test_input[0] + weight2 * test_input[1] + bias
    output = int(linear_combination >= 0)
    is_correct_string = 'Yes' if output == correct_output else 'No'
    outputs.append([test_input[0], test_input[1], linear_combination, output, is_correct_string])

# Print output
num_wrong = len([output[4] for output in outputs if output[4] == 'No'])
output_frame = pd.DataFrame(outputs, columns=['Input 1', '  Input 2', '  Linear Combination', '  Activation Output', '  Is Correct'])
if not num_wrong:
    print('Nice!  You got it all correct.\n')
else:
    print('You got {} wrong.  Keep trying!\n'.format(num_wrong))
print(output_frame.to_string(index=False))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem you're having might not be the output itself but some data not being set correctly previously in the exercise. I ran into the same problem with another exercise and was able to solve it by resetting the quiz first and then filling the necessary values step by step, each step followed by "Test run", which resulted in much nicer and more verbose error messages. So maybe reset your quiz first, fill in your values for `weight1`, `weight2` and `bias`, "Test run" and repeat the steps for all TODO items.